# Can old questions not be pushed to RSS readers when they're edited?

Tags: feature-request, meta, rss

Last night drj edited the tags on many posts.  This morning my RSS reader had 57 "new" items from homebrew.stackexchange.com.  Only they weren't new, they simply had their tags edited.  Can this site be configured so that the RSS feed isn't refreshed when questions are edited?

Comment: This happened again last night.  The tags were edited for dozens of posts and they all showed up in my RSS feed as new posts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we did change it recently so *title* edits do not spawn a new RSS post, at least:

[Prevent title edits to spawn a new RSS post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18051/prevent-title-edits-to-spawn-a-new-rss-post/22713)

Unfortunately in my opinion a tag edit is indeed a significant change and may warrant re-issuing the post in RSS -- like say if someone retags a question into my tag areas of interest, I may have never seen that post before.

**It seems the root issue here is that moderators/users should avoid manual mass retagging in favor of using the moderator tools to rename/merge tags** -- that is what I recommend in the future. If you "need" to retag 50+ posts, contact your friendly local diamond moderator (or us at Stack Exchange) and we have ways of making that happen without causing 50+ revisions on the site itself.